# Structured factoring

Tags: computational-number-theory

Is it easier to factor $$(ax + b) (ay+ c)=M$$ where $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ are known where $b$ and $c$ are similar in size and $a$ is approximately $b^{2/3}$ and unknowns $x,y\in\Bbb N$ and are approximately $b^{1/3}$?

Does coppersmith's techniques speed up factorization here?

---

Coppersmith's theorem $2$ in [Small Solutions to Polynomial Equations, and
Low Exponent RSA Vulnerabilities](https://www.di.ens.fr/~fouque/ens-rennes/coppersmith.pdf) says that:

"`Let $p(x, y)$ be an irreducible polynomial in two variables over $\Bbb Z$, of
maximum degree $\delta$ in each variable separately. Let $X, Y$ be bounds on the desired
solutions $x_0, y_0$. Define $\tilde p(x, y) = p(x X, yY )$ and let $W$ be the absolute value of the
largest coefficient of $\tilde p$. If $XY < W^{{2/(3\delta)}−\epsilon}2^{−14\delta/3}$ then in time polynomial in $(\log W, \delta, 1/\epsilon)$, we can find all integer pairs $(x_0, y_0)$ with $p(x_0, y_0) = 0$, $|x_0| < X$, and $|y_0| < Y$"'

In corollay $2$ he sharpens this to
"`With the hypothesis of Theorem $2$, except that $XY ≤ W^{2/(3\delta)}$,
then in time polynomial in $(\log W, 2^\delta )$, we can find all integer pairs $(x_0, y_0)$ with
$p(x_0, y_0) = 0$, $|x_0|\leq X$, and $|y_0| \leq Y$"'

Comment: Coppersmith indeed may help - check details at https://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2F3-540-68339-9_16

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev could you post a full solution?

Comment: Let's avoid further deleting and undeleting.

Comment: @ToddTrimble ok I posted this on cstheory as well (after deleting this) and I thought two active similar problems are disallowed. http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/35917/structured-factoring

Comment: deleted there now.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/a/199437/6043